# JavaScript constructors with and without new operator

Tags: javascript, constructor, new-operator

What is the difference in work of the following two chunks of code. Both seems to work similarly (I know that first is correct and second is not, but what the difference is?).

```
function Album(title, artist) {
    this.title = title;
    this.artist = artist;
    this.play = function() {
        console.log("Playing " + this.title + " - " + this.artist);
    };
}
var darkside = new Album("Dark Side of the Cheese", "Pink Mouse");
darkside.play();
```

And the same code, but constructor with `return this` and creating an instance of object without `new` operator

```
function Album(title, artist) {
    this.title = title;
    this.artist = artist;
    this.play = function() {
        console.log("Playing " + this.title + " - " + this.artist);
    };
    return this;
}
var darkside = Album("Dark Side of the Cheese", "Pink Mouse");
darkside.play();
```

Both returns the same result:

```
Playing Dark Side of the Cheese - Pink Mouse
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32978852/is-javascript-new-keyword-optional-for-javascript-api-feature

Comment: The second one doesn't create an instance. It adds the properties to the `window` object. If you try running that code in strict mode, it will crash since you'll be assigning properties to `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

This "works" because `this` without `new` resolves to `window` in a browser context and thus sets the `title` property of the `window` object to the `title` parameter.

You should use `new` so it's constructed in the right context and properly creates a new object with its own properties.

```
function Album() { alert(this==window); }; x = Album(); // true 
function Album() { alert(this==window); }; x = new Album(); // false
```

So if you made another instance, `this.title` would override the previous and so forth, and you wouldn't have any standalone object to store `title` with.

Comment: I ran all in Node, not in browser. So same logic work there if we interchange `window` with `global`?

Comment: @Alexander Yes, same thing.